# How to abstract enum attribute used by multiple models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activesupport-concern

I have a database attribute called `currency` which is used by multiple models. I'd like to create a concern (or similar) which defines the basic functionality of the `currency` attribute. If it was only used in a single model, I'd probably do something like this:

```rb
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  enum currency: [ :USD, :AUD ] 
  validates :currency, inclusion: { in: currencies.keys }
end
```

But since it's used by multiple models, I'd like to do something like this instead:

```rb
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  include Currency # maybe in a Concern?
  acts_as_currency :currency
end
```

The whole idea is to be able to do things like `Transaction.first.currency.USD?` and similar functionality that an enum attribute has, as well as defining the attribute validation in a single place.

How would you design that with Rails? Is there any preferred way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby, shared behaviours call for modules, ActiveSupport concerns provide cool syntactic sugar, [e.g. `included`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

```rb
# app/models/concerns/has_currency.rb
module HasCurrency
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    enum currency: [ :USD, :AUD ] 
    validates :currency, inclusion: { in: currencies.keys }
  end
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  include HasCurrency
end
```

We can give the user of our concern more freedom by going through a function instead, as you seem to suggest:

```rb
# app/models/concerns/has_currency.rb
module HasCurrency
  def acts_as_currency(column = :currency)
    enum column => [ :USD, :AUD ] 
    validates column, inclusion: { in: column.to_s.pluralize.keys }
  end
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  extend HasCurrency # Note the `extend`, not `include`
  acts_as_currency
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Matthieu Libeer answer I build this concern to use in all my models.

```rb
  module SharedEnums
    def acts_as_enum(*fields)
      @fields = fields
      dynamic_enums
    end

    private

    attr_reader :fields
    attr_accessor :enum_field

    def dynamic_enums
      fields.each do |enum_field|
        @enum_field = enum_field
        case enum_field
        when :attr_1 then format_enum('MODEL.ATTR_1')
        when :attr_2 then format_enum('MODEL.ATTR_2')
        end
      end
    end

    def format_enum(i18n)
      enum_array = I18n.t("activerecord.enums.#{i18n}").stringify_keys.keys
      enum({ "#{enum_field}": Hash[enum_array.zip(enum_array)] })
    end
  end
```

To use it is very simple by **extend SharedEnums** and add **act_as_enum** method to the needed models.

```rb
  class Model < ApplicationRecord
    extend SharedEnums
    acts_as_enum :attr_1, :attr_2
  end
```